# Preserve bookmarks when inserting image into pdf with pypdf

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I'm using pypdf to insert images into a pdf.
How do I keep the outlines (bookmarks) from the original pdf?

This is how I insert the image:

```
packet = io.BytesIO()
pdf_canvas = canvas.Canvas(packet)
pdf_canvas.drawImage(
    image=source_image_path,
    x=x_center,
    y=y_center,
    width=max_width,
    height=max_height,
    anchor="c",
    anchorAtXY=True,
    preserveAspectRatio=True,
    mask="auto",
)
pdf_canvas.showPage()
pdf_canvas.save()
packet.seek(0)

reader = PdfReader(destination_pdf)
stamp = PdfReader(packet)
writer = PdfWriter()

for i, page in enumerate(reader.pages):
    if i == page_target_index:
        page.merge_page(stamp.pages[0])
    writer.add_page(page)
writer.write(destination_pdf)
```